# Eclipse: large number of conflicts to resolve

Tags: eclipse, git, merge-conflict-resolution

After the latest merge with the master branch I ended up having a couple of hundred conflicting files in my branch. Resolving conflict in a single file is simple. I'm using Eclipse, so I just open Merge Tool, select 'Two-way comparison' instead of 'Three-way', click 'copy all non-conflicting changes from right to left', save changes and add it to the local repository.

But repeating this operation for a few hundred files manually is obviously not something I'd like to do. Is there a way to automate this process anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it by creating a new branch from master and moving my changes into this new branch. Fortunatelly I didn't have that much changes, so it wasn't that difficult.